# Prestosql converting UTC timestamp to local?

Tags: sql, data-science, presto, datetime-conversion, trino

How can I convert a timestamp field that includes day and time to local time in Prestosql? The fields look like

```
Region ID  |         Start Time utc       |       End Time utc
abc           2019-04-26 20:00:00.000   2019-04-26 23:00:00.000
cdx           2019-02-27 23:30:00.000   2019-02-28 01:00:00.000
```

I have the Region IDS so if I need to or if it makes it easier I can enter in the query the ids of the timezone I would need for that row.

I want to just return the local start and end time for that timezone.

the query is

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM table1
WHERE table1.day = date '2019-04-03' AND
     NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM table2
                 WHERE table1.id = table2.id AND
                       table1.timestamp >= table2.start_time AND
                       table1.timestamp <= table2.end_time
                 )
```

Where table 2 is the start and end time in which I want to convert to local times...

where the utc time is in the not exists clause for start and end time, how would I change that to local times ? not all the times would be the same timzone in america? There is a region Id field that I can use to link that region id to a timezone can I use that?

Comment: Does the datetime field contain any timezone information?

Answer (score 6):

From [presto's documentation](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/0.172/functions/datetime.html)

```
SELECT timestamp '2012-10-31 01:00 UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles';

2012-10-30 18:00:00.000 America/Los_Angeles
```

As the current timestamp you have is already in UTC, you can add the locality for the timestamp and get desired results.

Hope this helps

Comment: I have multiple timezones within the data set not just one how can I do that? I edited the question above to show the query in which I wanted to do this if that makes sense? @Shubham Pandey

Comment: Can you share some details about the values in the region Id fields? Also, how are you planning to map a given row with start and end date to the corresponding timezone?